# How to install Visual Basic 6 on a Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, installation, windows-server-2008, visual-basic

I'm trying to install Visual Basic 6 with Service Pack 6 obtained from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192461

But after extracting and double clicking the exe setup file nothing happens. How do I verify the VB6 installation? How to check which version is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That just downloads in an installer for the runtime (not the development environment itself).  And almost the first thing any installer does is check if the app is already installed.  Guess what?  The VB6 runtime is already part of Server 2003.

Comment: Should have double checked the link before posting my (now deleted) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually check the install location first. Default is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio

You can also verify that it has the latest service pack (SP6) it if it does run, open and under Help > About, next to the name of the application it will say SP6 (usually the splash screen updates as well, but some new computers do not show it long enough to see)